# How to display color and size in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, product-attribute, products, custom-attributes

I am using magento 2.2. I've both color and size attribute and I want to display  on frontend

[image]

I tried and colors are showing in left side:
[image]

Comment: Go to Stores -> Product (under attribute section) -> Select the attribute color and size -> Storefront Properties ->  Used in Product Listing option and set it to Yes .

Comment: I tried but it's not showing size and color

Comment: Did you flushed cache ?  Are the attributes assigned to the products ?

Comment: i did. yes, attributes are assigned to the products .

Comment: So it is working now ? Try a reindex and cache flush.

Comment: @kiran, are you using default magento theme or any other theme? try to use default theme and check these attributes appears on front or not.

Comment: if still attributes do not appear then share your listing page code.

Comment: I am using default theme.

Comment: Please see updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual swatches & text swatches visible on the storefront at the **listing page (below the product name)** is possible only with the **configurable products** so make sure that the product You have created is a configurable product & you have also created the **sub-products(child-products)** for it, and used the **size/color attributes** as variation options for the child products (You can use any as per your requirement).

**Please refer these images**

1. https://www.screencast.com/t/lZbVFd8j
2. https://www.screencast.com/t/bCE0d9gAv4NC

Now secondly make sure that the **attributes** you have used for the **variations** are of type **visual/Text Swatch** (in the property section) & are **visible on the store front on the listing page** (In the Storefront properties section).

**Please refer these images**

1. https://www.screencast.com/t/C1HVMrA0
2. https://www.screencast.com/t/SgID2exBI

Comment: if type is simple product then we can't display color and size.

Comment: You need to do hard code for it but it doesn't makes any sense as because the swatches are given there to show the variety you have into the single product that is to show the single kind of product in multiple size/color/designs etc.

Comment: It directly/indirectly links multiple simple products on the basis of there variation (single/multiple) & the similarities.

Comment: i tried with configurable products but now add to cart is not working. Configurable product is not added to cart in catalog page.
http://prntscr.com/ls48uf

Comment: Configurable products can't be added into the cart they are just made to show the variations of a same kind of products. On the reference of that configurable product end users are buying the simple products.For eg. you have a shirt which has *size = L* but you have that shirt available in 3 colors so you will create a single configurable product & it's 3 child products (Simple products) with all the 3 different colors.

Comment: Now when the end user will come to your site they will see a single product on your site with multiple color options availability (That is the configurable product) & then they will select the particular color which they want to buy. Which will indirectly points to the simple product (Child product) which has that color as an attribute into its properties. & so they will buy a simple product on the reference of that configurable product

Answer (score 0):

In order to make an attribute selectable in the list you need to mark it with "Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront" as "Yes".
Just to be safe put the flag "Used in Product Listing" to "yes" also.
In order to make it visible as a color swatch you need to set its type (Catalog Input Type for Store Owner) as "Visual swatch".
Make sure you rebuild your indexes when you are done.

Comment: I did, but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the Settings 
   -> Go to Stores -> Product
   -> Select the attribute color and size 
   -> Storefront Properties -> Used in Product Listing option and set it to Yes
   -> Used in Product Listing" to "yes"
2. Then try cache clean
3. Try a reindex and cache flush

Comment: What new you have suggested except @marius answer ?

Comment: I did, but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in list.phtml

```
<?php if($_product->isConfigurable()): ?>   //get attributes   <?php $attributes = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributes($_product) ?>   <?php if(count($attributes)): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach($attributes as $att): ?>
      <?php $pAtt=$att->getProductAttribute();
        //get the child products
        $allProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts(null, $_product);
        $frontValues =array() ?>
      <li><?php echo $pAtt->getFrontendLabel() ?>
       <ul>
       <?php foreach($allProducts as $p): ?>
         //check stock, status, ...
         //do not show unsaleable options
         <?php if(!$p->isSaleable()) continue; ?>
         <?php $out=$p->getAttributeText($pAtt->getName()); ?>
         <?php $frontValues[$out]=$out; ?>
       <?php endforeach ?>
        <li><?php echo implode('</li><li>', $frontValues) ?></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>   <?php endif ?> <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: This code is not working.